# Ho to update view holder text view value in adapter according to the adapter callback listner?

Tags: java, android, adapter

I have a recycle view adapter and it contains one text view, adapter getting a callback value from one of dialog fragment .I want to setText the holder's textview when getting callback value.In returnData method i am getting callback value, now I want to set that value in my holder text view named text value.

```
 public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener,MyDialogFragment.OnSetChangeListenerDialog{
     @Override
      public void returnData(String result) {
    setValue = result;
      }

       }

public MyAdapter(Activity activity, List<Detail> list, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {

    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
    this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

    final ListItemViewHolder viewHolder = new ListItemViewHolder(view);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        }
    });

    return viewHolder;
}
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    try {

        final ListItemViewHolder viewHolder = (ListItemViewHolder) holder;

        fina Detail item = list.get(position);
           viewHolder.textvalueTwo .setText(item.DESC());
        }


@Override
public void returnData(String result) {
    setValue = result;
}


   public class ListItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     private TextView textvalue;
        public ListItemViewHolder(final View parent) {
        super(parent);
          textvalue = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.textvalue);
            textvalueTwo = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.textvalueTwo);

            }
}}
```

Comment: If you want to update a single text view in a recycler view , you should know the index/row position of the item which you want to update. In your case which position you want to update?

Comment: i am showing a dialog fragment when i click on recycle view list..in dialog i can edit the list values,one update button is there in dialog faragment,when i click update the edited value should be updated in my recycle list,that my requirment..now am getting a call back value in my adapter when i edit dialog data,just want to update that value in my text view

Comment: post your callback code where you set returnData()

Comment: @user8838050 please see my answer. It should work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48071262/2470770

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using `list.set (index,model)`

```
 //Updating a particular item
public void updateItem(int index, YourModelClass item) {
    mList.set(index, item);
    notifyItemChanged(index);
}
```

This will update only the particular data of the RecyclerView
Try it do let me know

Update

In your `returnData()` add the below code

```
Detail item = list.get(getAdapterPosition());
item .setDescription(result);// updating the description value

updateItem(getAdapterPosition(), item); // calling the method to notify the change
```

Comment: notifyItemChanged will update the value of onBindViewHolder, you just need to pass the index and model data and it will work accordingly

Comment: when call back trigger can i update that particular textview inside that callback method?now i cant access that text view inside that method

Comment: you don't need to access the text view, to need to update the model class and then call the updateItem function and it will take care of the rest

Comment: can u just update in my code.am not understand where i have to call this method

Comment: @user8838050 add your Detail model to your Question also

Comment: returnData(String result)..there am getting call back value

Comment: @user8838050 : Happy  to help Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Method onBindViewHolder() will be called when you notify that data set changed.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // update your callback value here
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(setValue)) {
        viewHolder.textvalue.setText(setValue);
    }
}
```

and in your returnData():

```
@Override
public void returnData(String result) {
    setValue = result;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    // If you know exactly position of item changed
    // use  notifyItemChanged(position of item changed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
@Override
public void returnData(String result) {
    setValue = result;
    Detail item = list.get(position);
    item.DESC = setValue;
    mList.set(position, item);
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```